# When I try to concat an element it returns an empty array first and then it is always one behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create an array that in each click it concats the name of the pokemon that was clicked, I've been doing this by assigning the function `pushPokemon` but it is not working as expected because for now, when I click the first time one button it returns an empty array and the second time I click, it stores the first that it was clicked so it always goes one name behind the one that was actually clicked. I don't know how to go around this problem.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function Cards() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=12")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({ results }) => {
      setItems(results);
    });
}, []);

const pushPokemon = (e) => {

  var pokemon = e.target.innerHTML
  const newPokemon = clicked.concat(pokemon)
  setClicked(newPokemon)
  console.log(clicked)
}

    return (
        <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <button onClick={pushPokemon}>{item.name}</button>
        ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cards
```

Comment: Try to get rid of `newPokemon` variable and do `setClicked([...clicked, pokemon])`

Comment: does the same as the code I have now

Comment: `setClicked` won't update the state synchronously. `console.log(clicked)` will have stale data. Please check the duplicates